# Error #1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s) in Mysqlworkbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1241, mysql-function

I just try following query:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `cal1`(z DATE , y DATE) RETURNS float
BEGIN
SET @c= (SELECT a.StudentName, (b.marks/a.marks) as difference from (select Date, StudentName, marks from studenthistory2015 WHERE Date=z) as a INNER JOIN (select Date, StudentName, marks from studenthistory2015 where Date=y) as b on a.date=z and b.date=y WHERE a.date = z and b.date = y and a.StudentName=b.StudentName
);
RETURN @c;
END
```

Execution :

select student_history.cal1('2015-01-01', '2015-02-01');
But after execution, it shows
Error #1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

How should I resolve this query?

Comment: The error is because you are trying to stuff a result set into a variable. I don't see the point of a function here since you seem to want to calculate for all students.

Answer (score 0):

As [P.Salmon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6152400/p-salmon) said, you are trying to return a set of params, containing both strings and floats (i assume)

```
SELECT a.StudentName, (b.marks/a.marks) as difference
```

instead of returning a single variable, although you actually did declare, in your function, that you will return a float: `RETURNS float`

Maybe you can convert you function into a procedure, like mentioned in this [detailed answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23421816/3412965), answering another question related to yours.