# Is there way to convert oracle pipelined table function into mysql specific?

Tags: mysql, oracle, pipelined-function

Is there a way to convert oracle pipelined table function into mysql specific?

Requirement is to migrate from oracle to mysql. Existing oracle db has pipelined table function

Comment: MySQL doesn't support table valued parameters. See e.g. [How to use Table output from stored MYSQL Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17944871)

Comment: Unless your application uses the underlying database in only the most rudimentary way, refactoring from one database to another will almost certainly mean a significant amount of redesign and recoding. It will _not_ be a "lift and shift" sort of operation, as most modern databases and their features are not interchangeable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return table from MySQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23421771/how-to-return-table-from-mysql-function)